# I was trying to write a Python script to move the cursor to delete browser history, but when it exits vscode the script stops. Is there a fix?

Tags: python, pynput

```
from pynput.mouse import Button,Controller
import webbrowser
import time

mouse=Controller()

url = 'google.com'

chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

mouse.position = (1500, 55)
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)
mouse.position = (1400, 270)
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)
#has now exited vscode and stopped running
mouse.position(1000,100)
mouse.press(Button.left)
mouse.release(Button.left)

#webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

I initially thought it was not working because it was attempting to run all the cursor movements simultaneously, but it did not appear to be that, and exiting vscode seemed like the only possible issue.

Comment: Where do those mouse positions come from? How do you know the browser's buttons are at those coordinates?

Comment: I found said coordinates through trial and error.

Comment: Maybe use Pyautogui instead. I think it can search for menu and button items by name.